# Where to ask about support for broken gaming console parts?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a Nintendo 3DS gaming system that I'm looking to repair.

Here's the question I would be looking to ask:

> My circle pad for my 3Ds is broken, is there a way to have it fixed in a short time?
>
> I looked up how I could and everything involved carefully taking it apart. The cause of the problem was playing Smash bros for the 3Ds.

Is there a site on the network where can I ask this question?

Comment: Luna. I am sorry about your experience here. Your question is perfectly on topic and was asked relatively well. I could recommend a few changes for you and will make some of them so you can see. I've locked this post temporarily, which will prevent further downvotes - it's a double-edged sword, though, as it also prevents upvotes. I do understand that being downvoted feels quite uncomfortable. I've been here for years and still dread it. Downvoting is an important part of our system and we have specific reasons that we don't require comments with downvotes.

Comment: I am glad that you've gotten an answer that suits your needs, though it seems we may not have a site that will meet them. I do hope that your next interaction here will be better. I do recommend that you avoid complaining about downvotes. As I said, I do understand how much they can hurt. Particularly when you don't have a lot of reputation, losing what you have can impact your ability to use the site. Hopefully, after your question is edited, some may reconsider their votes and either remove the downvotes or add an upvote *but* that is their choice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately such a question would probably be not a good fit on any Stack Exchange site.

We prefer specific questions and this type of support questions cannot be answered within the boundaries of the Stack Exchange system. It would require back-and-forth discussion/communication between you and the answerers ("Does X help?", "Have you tried Y?").

**This type of question is better asked in forums and not on Q&A sites.**

What you could try is to ask for a certain work step ("I did X and try to do Y now but I have this problem: ...").

As @fbueckert said you could try [Arqade](https://www.gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). After scanning the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) I can find no other site that seems appropriate though. If you find one, be sure to read their help center /on-topic page to make sure your question is truly on-topic. Also consider taking the [tour](/tour) on the target site.

Answer (score 10):

We're a little shaky on hardware repair at Arqade; some questions work, while others don't.  We don't really have a specific policy surrounding it, although we do have questions about how to [reball a PS3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/52896/28182), or even how to [repair a controller](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56734/how-to-repair-a-malfunctioning-button-on-a-ps3-dualshock-controller).  We can likely take your question about replacing a circle pad.

But we'd be explaining on how you, yourself, can repair it.  Asking where to take it is a shopping recommendation, and will be closed on that alone.  If you're not willing to put in the work to fix it, then asking it on Arqade won't help you or anyone else.

Comment: I am asking in case it is to difficult

Comment: @Luna It doesn't matter; we can't help with that.  The best we can do is explain how to fix it yourself.

Comment: is there anywhere else I can ask this question?

Comment: @Luna There's not going to be anywhere on SE that can tell you where to take it; it's too specialized to your specific location, and not helpful to most readers.  If you don't want to ask it on Arqade, well, that's your choice, but it's going to be your best bet.

Comment: it is not my real location to make location private

Comment: Your location is irrelevant; I'm explaining why we can't answer where you can take it.

Comment: ok i will put it over when i can

Comment: how would this work


My circle pad for my 3Ds is broken, is there a way to have it fixed in a short time?

I looked up how I could and everything involved carefully taking it apart. The cause of the problem was playing Smash bros for the 3Ds. I want to do it myself but in case I will ask my grandpa.

Comment: sorry the formatting is not there

Comment: Nope.  Don't put constraints on it.  Just ask how to fix your circle pad due to overuse.  It'll go better if we see signs of prior research, such as other sites you've looked at, and why those don't work for you.  Your grandpa doesn't matter; questions are meant for not just yourself, but future readers as well.

Comment: my grandpa has worked with computers before

Comment: Still irrelevant.  Not everyone's going to have a grandpa familiar with computers.

Comment: ok I fixed it in my draft

Comment: We're going to assume at least a specific level of skill; you might get a step by step, you might not.  Asking for one sounds like a guide, which Arqade is rather allergic to, and will get it closed yet again for a recommendation.  Don't tell us how you want the problem solved; just stick to the problem.

Comment: i am used to having to do that